# How does scaling happen from Flutter to Android app?

Tags: android, flutter, scale, resolution

Let's say I have a 100px x 100px button defined in Flutter. The size is hardcoded, and not a percentage of screen size. I then created an apk, viewed the app screen on my phone, took a screenshot and transferred it to my laptop to check the actual size of the button. It's 263px x 263px.

My phone's screen size is 1080px x 2160 px, and the resolution is 401 ppi. Am I correct in assuming that scaling from code to app should happen by a factor of 2.5 (401/160)?

Or does scaling happen based on device pixel ratio, which for my device is 3.375?

In actual case, the scale factor I am getting is 2.63. How does this work? Moreover, how do I create an app with pixel perfect layout?

Comment: and what's the value of https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData/devicePixelRatio.html ?

Comment: @pskink It's 3.375.

Comment: maybe your button has some passing, instead I would first try a simple `Container` with fixed size 100x100 and solid color

Comment: Yes, it is defined as a container 100x100, black color.

Comment: and how did you take a screenshot? with `RepaintBoundary` and its `RenderRepaintBoundary.toImage` method (https://codesearchonline.com/flutter-screenshot/)?

Comment: No, I just ran the app on my phone, and took screenshot using phone's functionality. I imported the screenshot in Figma to check pixel dimensions. Is this a valid way to compare app with Figma design?